# "Firefox is already running" with -no-remote

Tags: firefox

I would like to open a new instance of Firefox. I tried

```
firefox -no-remote
```

and

```
MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1 firefox
```

as detailed [in the docs](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options). However I keep getting the message

```
Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, 
you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.
```

How can I launch a new instance of Firefox from command line?

Comment: @martineau I dont think you understand "new instance". That is 2 processes of `firefox`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [**-no-remote**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-no-remote) option is used for running multiple Firefox profiles at the same time. You are getting the *"Firefox is already running"* message because you are trying to open a second Firefox instance with the same profile.

You should be using this option as follows:

```
firefox -no-remote -P "Another Profile"
```

or

```
firefox -no-remote -profile "profile_path"
```

where `profile_path` is an absolute or relative (to **firefox.exe**) path.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need like you : running many instances of firefox on the same machine.

Basically, when you run an instance of firefox, there is a folder `.mozilla` in your `$HOME` is created ( if it is not existed yet). You can use the multi-profile solution if you want, as **iglvzx** mentioned above. So all user's profiles live in that .mozilla directory(database).

I have another trick which I think is more elegant than that solution. 
Create a directory to save a new firefox:

`$ mkdir $HOME/new_firefox`

`$ cd $HOME/new_firefox`

`$ tar xvf setup/firefox-33.0.tar.bz2`

Then create a small script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
HOME=$HOME/new_firefox
$HOME/firefox/firefox -no-remote &
```

So now run the scrip to have another instance of firefox. And your new user's profile live in `$HOME/new_firefox/.mozilla`.

If you use GNOME, just create a `new_firefox.desktop` file and put it in `/usr/share/applications` directory or in `$HOME/.local/share/applications` directory. The `Exec` argument in that file is `Exec=/home/your_name/path-to-your-script`. If you don't know how to create one, see an existed one in either of 2 above directory.

Comment: So you manually download each new version of the firefox-*.tar.bz2